# The better way to show the steps of equation solution

Tags: amsmath

Is there any better way to show the steps of equation solution? The following does not look good, IMHO.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
x^2 &= 25 \\
x^2 &= 5^2      & \text{or}&&       x^2 &= (-5)^2 \\
x   &=5             & \text{or}&&           x   &=-5
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would simply write  x² = 5² iff x = ±5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{witharrows}
\usepackage{amstext} % for \text
\begin{document}
\begin{DispWithArrows*}[wrap-lines]
x^2 = 25 
& \Longleftrightarrow x^2-25 = 0 \\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x-5)(x+5) = 0 
\Arrow{a product equals zero iff a factor equals zero} \\
& \Longleftrightarrow x=5 \text{ or } x=-5
\end{DispWithArrows*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

Comment: Is using double arrows per line an internationally accepted notation?

Comment: Yes. It's the international symbol for the logical equivalence. And here, as you want to resolve an equation, you have to do a raisoning by equivalence (in order to have the solutions, all the solutions, only the solutions...)